# Вызов alert(alert(1))

Tags: javascript

alert(alert(1)) - выводит undefined
Не могу понять почему так выводит, потому что мыслю как то, что в алерте в скобках выведет 1 и соответственно получится alert(1) и в конце останется 1
А также в какой последовательности будет работать код alert( alert(1) && alert(2) );

Comment: Не следует задавать новый вопрос путем изменения текста вопроса через пятнадцать часов после его публикации.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops

Comment: Не сохранился измененный вариант сразу

Answer (score 10):

"Мыслить" - это здорово, но иногда проще прочитать:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

> Window alert() Method
>
> Return Value: No return value
>
> (Возвращает: Ничего не возвращает)

Не возвращает:

```js
var test = alert(1);
console.log(test);
```

Bозвращает:

```js
var test = confirm("Are you sure?");
console.log(test);
```

Bозвращает:

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

console.log(multiply(2, 3));
```

Не возвращает:

```js
function multiplyAndShow(a, b) {
  var c = a * b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = c;
}

console.log(multiplyAndShow(2, 3));
```

```html
<span id="result">empty</span>
```

Comment: когда alert(1) выводится 1 - это является возвращением? Думаю я из-за этого путуаюсь

Comment: @Elvis `alert` выводит `1`, потому что это то, что делает `alert` - показывает окошко с строковым представление того, что передано ему в качестве параметра. Никакого отношения к значению, возвращаемому функцией `alert` это не имеет.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста,привести пример функции, которая возвращает значение?

Comment: @Elvis добавил пример в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое! Правильно ли я поняла, что возвращает что-то - это функции, где надо на что-то ответить или что-то ввести? То есть там обычно не одно действие

Comment: @Elvis Не совсем. "Возвращает" - функция предназначена для того, чтобы отдать что-то коду, который ее вызвал, ну и возможно выполнить перед этим какие-то действия. В коде функции присутствует команда `return [something];`. "Не возвращает" - функция ничего отдает коду, который ее вызывает. Посмотрите два примера функции с умножением - в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

выведет сначала 1 (внутренний алерт), а потом undefined (то, что вернул внутренний алерт), и в конце останется undefined (то, что вернет внешний алерт)

Comment: Не до конца понимаю. Выше написали, что ничего не возвращает, но Вы пишете во 2 скобках что он вернул внутренний алерт :(

Comment: @Elvis в терминах javascript-a - "ничего не возвращает" это то же самое, что "возвращает `undefined`"

Answer (score 4):

Функция `alert()` *не возвращает никакого значениа*. Это значит, что

```
alert(1)
```

не явлается удобным параметром для *никакой* функции, в том числе самой функции `alert()`:

```
alert(alert(1))    // alert(1) ошибочный параметр для alert()
```

Comment: что значит _ошибочный_ параметр?

Answer (score 1):

каждая функция решает небольшую задачу:
1. ей передаются параметры;
2. она выполняет некоторые действия;
3. функция возвращает результат или ничего (undefined).

функция alert:
1. получает в качестве параметра строку 
2. выводит эту строку на экран
3. возвращает пустой результат 'undefined', который передаётся второй из двух функций в качестве аргумента