# Ошибка в функции(undefined)

Tags: javascript

- По идеи скрипт должен вывести одно сообщение 'Опа',
- но после него alert выводит **undefined**.
- Как устранить этот баг?

```js
function opa() {
  alert('Опа');
}

alert(opa());
```

Comment: по хорошему, функция должна возвращать что-то, у вас ничего не возвращается, а вызывается метод alert, по-этому и undefined

Comment: Куда именно возвращать)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function opa() {
  return 'Опа';
}

alert(opa());
```

Comment: А что делает return?

Comment: @Black_Viper Вот именно! https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+return+in+programming&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS847CA847&oq=what+is+return+in+progr&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.13039j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: А можно на человеческом языке)? 
И это описание return не в js((

Comment: @Black_Viper https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769159/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-alertalert1

Answer (score 1):

В Javascript функция [может вернуть результат](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#vozvrat-znacheniya), который будет передан в вызвавший её код, а может выполнять другое любое действия не возвращая результат работы функции.

Для возврата значения используется ключевое слово `return`.
**P.S:** Весь код на следующей строке после `return;` - будет игнорироваться. Подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

К примеру есть функция `sum`:

```js
function sum (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(sum(2, 2))
```

Как видите, при вызове, функция вернёт сумму аргументов `a и b`.
Чтобы наглядно это увидеть, мы вызываем `console.log()`, и первым параметром передаем функцию `sum` с [аргументами](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#parametry) `2 и 2`
И так, рассмотрим ваш пример.

Вы хотите, чтобы при вызове функции `alert`, у вас вывелось сообщение на экран.
Рассмотрим ваш код:

```js
function opa(){ // декларируем функцию
  alert('Опа'); // вызываем alert с сообщением Опа
}; // закрываем блок функции

/**
  * здесь, вы вызываете alert, который сам по себе уже выводит сообщения на экран, 
  * однако вы передаете в него функцию, которая ничего не возвращает, а всего-лишь 
  * вызывает еще один alert с сообщением Опа, в итоге вы ведите два сообщения,
  * первое сообщение из функции opa, второе это уже вызов alert вне функции opa
 */
alert(opa());
```

Правильнее в данной ситуации написать вот так
**Код от Igor**:

```js
function opa() { // декларируем функцию
  return 'Опа'; // вовзращаем строку "Опа"
} // закрываем блок функции

alert(opa()); // вызываем alert, первым параметром передаем вызов функции opa
```

Итак, разбираемся.
Вызываем `alert`, внутри `alert` находится еще одна функция - вызываем её, видим `return "Опа"`, возвращаем значение наверх и теперь уже функция `alert` выведет вам сообщение, которое вернула функция.

Если хотите изучать javascript, вам понадобятся такие ресурсы как [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/) и [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/).
Надеюсь помог, удачи!

Answer (score 0):

К примеру:
result = prompt(title, [default]);
 default - необязательное значение, есть одно но.
Второй параметр является необязательным, но если не указать его, то Internet Explorer установит значение "undefined" в поле для ввода.

Comment: Говорят, что функция должна возвращать что-то и куда-то.
Можно объяснить нубу)?

Comment: Передаваемые значения копируются в параметры функции и становятся локальными переменными.
Функции имеют доступ к внешним переменным. Но это работает только изнутри наружу. Код вне функции не имеет доступа к её локальным переменным.
Функция может возвращать значение. Если этого не происходит, тогда результат равен undefined.


Да return обязательное значение так как функция должна, что то вернуть, или изменённое свойство или нет.